# Cannot Add Account Owner to Azure EA Enrollment

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-gov

I need some help with this and I couldn't find any solution on the internet.

I need to **change the ownership** for an Azure Gov Subscription under an Enterprise Agreement Enrollment so first I need to create the new Account following the related [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/billing-subscription-transfer#transfer-ea-subscription-billing-ownership)

The current "Account Owner" is the Initial Account *gov.**admin**@govtenant.onmicrosoft.com*

[image]
[image]

It's a work account in our "Azure AD Free" tenant and I have full control over it
It's also a Global Administrator in that tenant

[image]

The new account to add (*gov.**user**@govtenant.onmicrosoft.com*) is also a "Global Administrator" and exists in the same tenant

[image]

When I try to add it, the portal returns this error:

> The login information provided is not a valid user.
>   If you believe you have received this message in error, please contact customer support.

[image]

But when I try to add an account from the tenant that we have in Azure Commercial (with "Azure AD for Office 365") ...

[image]

... the error seems to be correct.

> The enrollment is in a cloud that is different from that of the user.

[image]

---

So far, I know that the "gov.admin@govtenant.onmicrosoft.com" account was signied up to the EA portal using an email from the Comercial Tenant (comtenant)

Also "govtenant" is a custom domain for the Comercial Tenant

[image]

So, what am I doing wrong?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Does gov.user comply with all these: "The target account must be a valid Azure Commerce account to be a valid target for transfers. For new accounts, you are asked to create an Azure Commerce account when signing in to the Azure Enterprise portal. For existing accounts, you must first create a new Azure subscription before the account is eligible" ?e hold of it

Comment: Hi @Alfredo, thanks for your response. What do you mean by an "Azure Commerce" Account? user.gov is a work account but the email is from another tenant (commercial tenant in portal.azure.com) so I need an email from the Gov tenant. But, the Gov Tenant is an "Azure AD Free". I've already read about the ["Change account owner"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/ea-portal-get-started#change-account-owner) Doc and couldn't figure out what I'm missing here. Maybe I'm not thinking this in the right way or I'm missing some background. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the response, actually I will reach within AAD team to get information about what exactly makes an account valid and then come back to you. In th meantime if you can share some details about the gov.user@govtenant.onmicrosoft.com user such as admin roles that might help.